# Cannot save simple form element string to DB (Rails, SqLite)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

So I have a simple flow, where I am filling out a simple form, saving some basic information to a database, and then want to spit out that information on a page, specific to that item.

Everything is working as expected (form submission, redirect to the correct page (/books/:id), but once I am at that page, I cannot extract the string I saved and if I query the database using `select * from books;` I get the following results, showing that the record is successfully inserted, but without the `name` string, it seems.

```
4||2015-01-11 09:59:48.177701|2015-01-11 09:59:48.177701
```

So as you can see, the form is being submitted and the book record is succesfully created, but the "`name`" string is not being inserted.

**Help much appreciated!!**

My new book form (`/app/views/books/new.html`)

```
<h1>Create a new e-book</h1>

<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

The books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def new
     @book = Book.new
  end

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.new(params[:book])
    redirect_to @book
  end

  private
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

The book.rb model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The migration file where I created the table

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The show book page (`app/views/books/show.html.erb`)

```
<p>Books view</p>

<p>
  <strong>Book Name:</strong>
  <%= @book.name %>
</p>
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  get "dashboard" => "dashboard#dashboard", :as => "dashboard"
  get "books" => "books#books", :as => "books"
  get "newbook" => "books#new", :as => "newbook"

  root 'home#index'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :books

end
```

Comment: can you please post your `/views/books/show.html.erb`

Comment: There you go, added!

Comment: I think I may have something - am I missing the validators inside the model? i.e `validates :name, presence: true`    @OptimusPette

Comment: absence of a presence validator cannot prevent the field from being saved in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 @book = Book.create(book_params)
```

Instead of

```
 @book = Book.new(book_params)

 @book.save
```

Comment: Hmm, Same problem, blank record inserted into the DB.

Comment: If I add 
`validates :name, presence: true
validates :name, uniqueness: true`

to my model, I then get a template error (no books#create) - but could that be on the right track?

Comment: @user2656127 is your field `:title` or `:name` ?

Comment: Sorry, it is `:name, updated my last comment. That was not the issue, just a copy paste error.

Comment: If I just use `@book = Book.create(book_params)´ as you suggested, I get the following error `Missing template books/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/action/auth/app/views"`  - Do I need to create a new view for create?

Comment: No, there is no create view. can you please go to the rails console and try to create a new book from there, and check the errors

Comment: INSERT INTO books (name) VALUES("Book Title"); right?

Comment: Hmm, no error - it did insert the record properly (without the timestamps of course)

Comment: Yep, and now if I navigate to books/:id - I do spit out the name accurately. So, it's definitely something to do with the inserting/creation. @OptimusPette

Comment: on the root directory of your rails app, type `rails c` then do `book = Book.new(name: 'book name')` then `book.save` if it saves try printing `book.name`

Comment: WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Book: name    @OptimusPette

Comment: are you using rails 4 or rails 3? if you are using rails 4 please check your book_params method

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.1.0 - how do you mean check the method? Anything in particular @OptimusPette (Thanks btw)

Comment: The mass-assignment error should not appear on rails 4 unless the `:name` attribute is not being permitted properly or you are using protected_attributes gem.

Comment: I am using the protected_attributes gem by the way @OptimusPette

Comment: I have added an answer on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok, So to debug this, you could do the followings

1 ) open your rails console and try to create a save a record

`Book.create!(name: 'sample name')`

and if this works, that means your model part works, So its something to do with the controller and params. If this doesnt works, post the error log as it might probably give some clues.

2 ) run your rails server and try to save the record from your page. observe the parameters passing from the webpage to controller. (you could use `chrome dev tools - chrome` or `firebug - firefox` for this. So that you have an idea of if the actual value is passed to the controller

3 ) use some kind of a debug tool (like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) ) and in the controller after create function

```
def create
  binding.pry 
  ... code ..
end
```

and try to check the params you are getting

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Remove the protected_attributes gem from your `gemfile` run the `bundle` command restart the server and try creating a book. If you want to keep the protected_attributes gem, then in your `create` action you do

```
@book = Book.new(params[:book])
```

and then in your model you do

```
attr_accessible :name
```

Comment: Thanks @optimuspette NoMethodError in Books#books
Showing /home/action/auth/app/views/books/books.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: do you have a `books` action in your `BooksController`?

Comment: Nope. my BooksController (books_controller.rb) is above. How would that books action look?

Comment: what about a `books.html.erb`? in your views?

Comment: Yep, that has the following code

`<p>
  <strong>Book Name:</strong>
  <%= @book.name %>
</p>`

Comment: how is the route and controller action that renders this view? The error shows that your view has no access to the `@book` instance

Comment: Added my routes.rb file to the bottom of my post. Thanks so much for the all the help @OptimusPette

Comment: Now that I think about it - I think that's the problem. How do I set that view so it can access the @book instance?

Comment: There is something wrong with your `get "books" => "books#books", :as => "books"` I am not sure what you want it to do but you should have a `books` action in `BooksController` that have access to `book_id` parameter for that route to work

Comment: If you want a list of all books on that view, then replace `get "books" => "books#books", :as => "books"` with `get "books" => "books#index", :as => "books" and restart the server`